# Nontraditional summer employment for academics

Tags: academic-life, summer-school

I'm a research mathematician, probably soon to be tenured, and I've been wondering what 'non-traditional' summer employment options are out there, involving either teaching or research. (I enjoy both!)

Programs like [PROMYS](http://www.promys.org) would be fun and rewarding, but it appears that they are looking to hire students rather than faculty. [Duke TIP](http://tip.duke.edu/node/15) seems to be one possibility.

In a different direction, I know that [IDA](http://www.pathwaystoscience.org/programhub.aspx?sort=SUM-InstforDefenseAnalyses-Math) hires mathematicians, although I am rather ambivalent about government surveillance and am not sure I would want to work in such a position.

What other opportunities are out there? I am especially interested in established programs that attract a relatively large community of other researchers and/or students, and am quite happy to travel. For the moment I don't think I would be effective in a leadership role, or in creating an opportunity from scratch.

Comment: My impression of Duke TIP, from years ago, was that it is all about promoting Duke.

Comment: Some foreign governments offer funding for short term visiting researchers.

Comment: Mathematical institutes like IPAM, IMA, ICERM, etc. have long programs, some of which are during the summer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about NASA?

I personally know a fair number of faculty who have spent summers working at Langley and Kennedy, and I can pull up a quick application form for [JPL's summer faculty research program](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/edu/intern/apply/jpl-summer-faculty-research-program/). A lot of people, faculty and researchers included, put NASA on a very high pedestal, but it is definitely an attainable position. I am not very knowledgeable of the limitations placed upon you, but I do know fairly valuable work is done, perhaps even outside of your comfort zone -- I know of a fluid dynamicist who worked at skunkworks in Kennedy, for one.